# Terminal hangs while executing wvdial startup for 3G stick

Tags: pi-zero, internet, raspi-config, usb-hub

I have connected a Rpi zero module to an USB hub(unpowered) and using one port for a 3G stick. 2 other ports are being used for Keyboard and mouse. I was able to install wvdial and update the .conf file as per the APN details for the service provider. Here is the photo of the wvdial.conf file,

[image: Wvdial.conf for Congstar UMTS stick]

Now i ran the following line

Sudo wvdial congstar &

The terminal then hangs with the following lines being displayed. Internet connectivity works after maybe one minute. But the terminal stays frozen as below

[image: Dont know what to do! hope for the best?]

The internet works just fine. But I have to restart the terminal everytime i hit the command to start the stick.
Any ideas ? Something wrong in my .conf file?

I use the same with a Rpi 3 model and it works just fine without any warnings.

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

*Reading the f*****g manual*: i.e. the `man`page for `wvdial`(1):

> : "... If all of this fails, **wvdial** just runs ***pppd***(8) and hopes for the best. It will bring up the connection, and then wait patiently for you to drop the link by pressing CTRL-C."

So I do not think it is doing anything wrong, it is just sitting there, reporting stuff on stdout/stderr (the terminal screen) until you quit (with <Ctrl>-C) or you can send it a SIGINT {`sudo kill -2`<the pid Of wvdial> } from another terminal window or remote login.

BTW Given that you are using a name and password of "tm" for both and the remote end is not responding to them - or anything else, you may actually have a case where `Stupid mode` could be `on`!

8-)